# Having black coloured labels for pie chart in vega lite

Tags: javascript, vega-lite, vega

I was referring to [pie chart examples](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/arc.html#examples) of vega-lite.

I modified one of them to show percentage values as follows:

```js
vegaEmbed("#pie-chart", {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": 1, "value": 4},
      {"category": 2, "value": 6},
      {"category": 3, "value": 10},
      {"category": 4, "value": 3},
      {"category": 5, "value": 7},
      {"category": 6, "value": 8}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"calculate": "datum.value + ' %'", "as": "label"}],
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "stack": true},
    "color": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal", "legend": null}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "arc"}
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 120},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "label", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Data visualizer</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@5"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="pie-chart"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly and renders following:

[image]

However, I wanted those percentage labels in black color. So I referred [text mark](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/text.html) and tried following:

```
"mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 120, "color":"black"},
```

But this does not makes any changes to above output.

I also [tried putting `color` as encoding](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIZw1LsJOsyGA7nRiHETOMtXLDypJhUiioBKKigxEiCDGpoANqgUAHkbOoAnmgAjEqR0XBoACwAvgqJyWSpGagATDlRMWgAbCVlmCnpaADMdXlZAAwtIEltFR2oBT0NqJ2Dw+1VYpP5qADss+WVTUtoABxFALolIJjqSLIQAGapCPFlglAMgsloIZgMCJS5MYYA1IYA5IYAKT-YJICAvJ6eQQgA5KOCyKBsZQ0WRkNCgehwQIYkAXGyCZQvL75JSYNI4ZYgACODDOOkCOlIwQggSgAGs0CcYkckYJUrj8XBCS85qMMmSKVTZGwEKiosELGQEUTULJHoIikcnmk4OpbiBkOpOeFjlKXvYoLDBkaTZjzeg2gAPTDBU4ohgQ1CZaoDeGI5Go9Gm52u01CkXoKHC4LkykvGVy2QK3lsfn600kl5MJ4c60HIpAA):

```
{
  "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 120},
  "encoding": {
    "text": {"field": "label", "type": "nominal"},
    "color": {"value":"black"}
  }
}
```

But it rendered following:

[image]

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": 1, "value": 4},
      {"category": 2, "value": 6},
      {"category": 3, "value": 10},
      {"category": 4, "value": 3},
      {"category": 5, "value": 7},
      {"category": 6, "value": 8}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"calculate": "datum.value + ' %'", "as": "label"}],
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "stack": true},
    "color": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal", "legend": null}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "arc"}
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "radius": 120, "fill":"black"},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "label", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Just a follow up question: how one can build conceptual intuition about where should a thing go? That is, what was conceptually wrong with believing that it should be the property of text encoding?

Comment: Just practice I'm afraid. Work your way through all the examples and things should start to become more second nature.

Comment: Yes thats what I felt. But I believe I need to watch the video vega researchers published. I guess they explained the concepts in more depths and how to grammar json is conceptualized.

Comment: If you get stuck just post here. Someone usually answers quite quickly.